# Wordpress Multisite plugin delegation

Tags: plugins, multisite, multisite-user-management

I'm currently familiarising myself with the Wordpress Multisite feature, but there appears to be an option missing:

**If I want to install a specific plugin for one of my sites, but not for any of the other sites, is there a way I can do this without the plugin being displayed as available on the other sites?**

As far as I'm aware, I have to add the plugin at Network level and make it available to ALL sites, not just a specific site, which means all of my other sites will have that plugin displayed when you go to the Plugin section.

This is not practical in my scenario, as I'm using Wordpress Multisite as way to manage several client websites that have absolutely no link whatsoever. So I could potentially have a recruitment website that requires a powerful recruitment plugin as one of my sites, but that plugin will also display for a ecommerce site I have.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Try Plugin commander http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-commander/ it gives you the control you need.

You don't have to sitewide activate all plugins and you can keep plugins hidden from other users.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve having to bolt on an extra plugin.